# Anyone explain to me this video?

Tags: fourier-transform, dft, laplace-transform

I was watching a
[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hewTwm5P0Gg)
in time 24:48
I would like to know where you got the value

$$0.9 (z^2 -1.14z + 0.941)$$ and $$z^2 - 1.0232z + 0.757$$

Does anyone explain how he got those numbers?

Comment: no, sorry, I'm really not going to watch 24:47 minutes of video to understand your question. Could you try to explain what they're doing, what you understand and what you not understand about it? Also, never discount the possibility of Youtube videos being not the best educational source, or correct all the time.

Comment: https://tinyurl.com/s4rcff9  , https://tinyurl.com/wpz8yqx

Answer (score 2):

Two conjugate poles:

$(z-(0.51+0.7i))(z-(0.51-0.7i)) = z^{2} - 1.02z +0.76$

Two conjugate zeros:

$(z-(0.57+0.78i))(z-(0.57-0.78i)) = z^{2} - 1.14z +0.94$

---

```
>> roots([1 -1.14 0.941])

ans =

   0.5700 + 0.7849i
   0.5700 - 0.7849i

>> roots([1 -1.0232 0.757])

ans =

   0.5116 + 0.7038i
   0.5116 - 0.7038i
```

Comment: ok but how do you get 0.76 and 0.94?

Comment: If you don't know that then you either need to learn how to expand brackets, or learn how it works with complex numbers

Comment: Me too wonder, how you got $0.76$ and $0.94$. I see it $0.75010$ and $0.93330$ instead.

Comment: Put the equation on the right in here: https://www.mathsisfun.com/quadratic-equation-solver.html